# unable to change navbar's font color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the navbar's background color to blue and the links color to white. I am not able to change the links on the navbar to white. I'm not doing something right. Not sure what. Appreciate the help!

```css
 .navbar-default  {
 background-color: #2196f3;
 
}
.navbar a{
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Home</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap/css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top navbar-default ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
   </div>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drive</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Zipcode</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help/FAQ's</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Conatct us</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
<script src = "js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I click on *Run code snippet* here, I get a blue background with white links ...!

Comment: Same, the code snippet works fine

Comment: code snippet does not load bootstrap styling, so it work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific with your CSS rules. See [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Working Example:

```css
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}
.navbar.navbar-default ul > li > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drive</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Zipcode</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Help/FAQ's</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Conatct us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: you were too fast for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap have many default style.

You code is not working is because bootstrap override your css(same as @Kirito mention).

You can change css to this, it work:

```
.navbar div{
    background-color: #2196f3 !important;

}
.navbar a{
    color:white !important;
}
```

However, better solution is **customize your bootstrap**. link: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

This approach will get cleaner code and less problem

Comment: I tried this and it work. However, my key point is use **bootstrap's customize** . I think it will be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.navbar a` rule set and add:

```
/* change brand text color */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand
{
    color:white;
}

/* change list links text color */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a
{
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific about your selectors or other selectors (defined in bootstrap's CSS) will apply as they are likely more specific

This is all better explained in the [specificity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

See sample code below.

```css
nav.navbar-default {
  background-color: #2196f3;
  background-image: none;
}
nav.navbar-default .navbar-brand,
nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Drive</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Zipcode</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Help/FAQ's</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Conatct us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


</html>
```